# string after forward slash

Tags: java, regex

The pattern that I have so far using regex

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^.*?\/\/([^:\/\s]+)(.*(?=\?|\#))", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

While working on the string https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-syntax, it successfully grabs just the / as I am trying to avoid ? and #, however the problem arises when I try https://url.spec.whatwg.org/

The whitespace at the end is preventing it from finding / in group 2. I have tried including \p{Blank} in the lookahead, however it did nothing.

"https://www.google.com/search?q=Regular+Expressions&num=1000"

Same for the string above; it grabs the /search before the ? but as soon as there as I try "https://www.google.com/search" it breaks down.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `The whitespace at the end is preventing it from finding` just [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) it. Also, [read this SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: I've tried trimming all white space, however it still cant find the token without anything after the /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below assumes that the input will be URL and we'll take only a bit of it without the `query string`. Try this

```
(http)s?:\/\/[^#?]+
```

You could change the `(http)s?` with `(.+)` if you want your old multi-catch approach.. although we could define protocols directly like `(http|ftp|...)s?`.

[Online Test](https://regex101.com/r/bxqWSf/1)